# Content assist in eclipse JSDT javascript editor fails using object notation

Tags: eclipse, content-assist, jsdt

I'm using eclipse JSDT and I have a javascript object declaration that looks like this:

```
var rs1 = {};
rs1.person1 = {};
rs1.person1.phone = "hg";
rs1.person1.name = "lk";
```

Content assist will pull up rs1 properties (**rs1.person1.name**) in the editor if I add it to a file in the project javascript include path user library, but the following notation

```
var rs1 = {person1:{ phone:"hg", name:"lk"}};
```

then content assist will only go as far as **rs1.person** and stop. If I use this same JSON notation directly in my javascript, then content assist works as expected. It just doesn't work when I add it the project include path.

I've been struggling with this for a few days but I can't find a way to make it work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just tried and when I add the file defining rs1 to my include path, and try to access it from another file, I do not get any completions either.  I am in mac, so I do not think this is a linux-only thing.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this may be a problem with eclipse on linux (I'm running ubuntu). I downloaded a fresh copy of indigo to ensure that it wasn't some third party plugin that was causing the problem, but the content assist was still not working.

Just tried it on a windows box this morning and content assist works as expected.